# Change in wavefunction due to adiabatic potential in time dependent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I've been puzzled equation (2.2) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.2021),

[image]

I've looked into time-dependent perturbation theory and the adiabatic theorem and the closest I could come to deriving this was showing that

$$
i \hbar \dot{c_k} = (E_k - i \hbar < \psi_k | \dot{\psi}_n > ) c_k - i \hbar \sum_{n \neq k} \frac{\dot{H}_{kn}}{E_n-E_k} c_n,
$$

where $| \Psi_n(t)> = \sum_n c_n(t) | \psi_n (t) >$ and $H_{kn} = <\psi_k| H |\psi_n>$.

I was wondering if someone could direct me to a derivation of equation (2.2) as I am struggling to connect perturbation theory with this result.

Comment: Consider to use \langle and \rangle instead of $<$ and $>$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adiabatic expansion is not the same as that of time dependent perturbation theory. In tradition T-D perturbation we expand in a complete set of states of the *original* time-independent Hamiltonian. In the adiabtic perturbation series we expand in terms of the eigenstates of the *current* time-dependent Hamiltonian.

Start from the time dependent Schroedinger equation
$$
i\partial_t|\psi_0(t)\rangle =\hat H(t)|\psi_0(t)\rangle
$$
and expand
$$
|\psi_0(t)\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n|n,t\rangle \exp\left\{-i\int_0^t E_0(t')dt'\right \}.
$$
Choose the complete orthonormal set of states $|n,t\rangle$ to be  eigenstates of
the ``snapshot''   hamiltonian,  $\hat H(t)$,
$$
\hat H(t)|n,t\rangle=E_n(t)|n,t\rangle.
$$
Insert the expansion into the Schroedinger equation,  take components and assume that
$|\psi_0(t)\rangle $  stays close to $|0,t\rangle$  so that $|a_0|$ is close to unity, and the other coeficients are small. This leads to
$$
\dot a_0+a_0\langle 0,t|\partial_t|{0},t\rangle \approx 0\\
a_m\approx ia_0\langle{m,t}|{\partial_t}|{0,t}\rangle \frac1{(E_m-E_0)}.
$$
Up to first order in time-derivatives of the states, we find
$$
|\psi_0(t)\rangle =e^{-i\int_0^t E_0(t)dt+i\gamma_{Berry}}\left\{|{0,t}\rangle+
i\sum_{m\ne 0}\frac{|{m,t}\rangle\langle{m,t}|{\partial_t}|{0,t}\rangle}{E_m-E_0}+\ldots\right\}.
$$
Berry's phase is the solution  $a_0=\exp \{i\gamma_{Berry}\}$ to the first of the two equations above. It is a phase because   a $|{0},t\rangle$ being  normalized means that $\langle 0,t|\partial_t|{0},t\rangle$ is pure imaginary.  This  phase-factor is needed  to take up the
slack between the  arbitrary   phase choice  made when defining
$|0,t\rangle$, and the  specific phase selected by the  Schroedinger equation
as it evolves the state.

Comment: Ah thanks for the response, thats been really helpful. I was just wondering if you could clarify the physical difference between traditional and adiabatic T-D perturbations? Is it simply that in one (traditional) the time dependent term is small with respect to the time independent term and in the other the time dependent term varies slowly enough that the state stays in the $n^{th}$ eigenstate as t evolves?

Comment: Yes: one is *small* perturbation to $H$, and the other is *slow* change in $H$.